# PHP - redirection under Chrome

Tags: php, html, google-chrome

I have a problem with the following code:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("config.php");

if(isset($_SESSION['location']) && !empty($_SESSION['location'])) {
   $location = $_SESSION['location'];
   $url = ABS_PATH . $location;
   unset($_SESSION['location']); 
   header('Location: ' . $url);
}
```

The value of     $url is:

```
http://www.domain.eu/somepage
```

and value passed to header() is:

```
Location: http://www.domain.eu/somepage
```

It is ok under Opera, IE (7,8,9) and Firefox but unfortunately it is not working under Chrome and I have no idea why. Mentioned code sample comes from file index.php and it is execuded every time You load a page.  I have other file (display.php) to which I send url via AJAX request. File display.php sets value of $_SESSION['location'] and returns content of page. In browsers other than Chrome when I refresh page it redirects me to proper URL. During debuging I noticed that even when I put die(); after

```
unset($_SESSION['location']);
```

it does not execute it, but when i put it before it works. Can anyone have any idea how to solve my problem?

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: what is the actual $url value? what HTTP header is sent?

Comment: add session_write_close() after modifying the session, and exit() after sending the header

Comment: $url is set to http://www.domain.eu/somepage
and value passed to header is:
Location: http://www.domain.eu/somepage

Comment: There is `http://` in it but it was cut out in here while pasting. I tried session_write_close() after unseting $_SESSION and after setting it in file display.php but it did not work. Also added exit after header();. The problem seems to be in condition because when do:

`unset($_SESSION['location']);
 session_write_close();
 die($url);` it does not die the $url but when I try:

`die($url);
unset($_SESSION['location']);
 session_write_close();` it works. 
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
session_start();
$_SESSION['location'] = 'http://www.google.com';
if(isset($_SESSION['location']) && !empty($_SESSION['location'])) {
    $location = $_SESSION['location'];
    header("location: ".$location);
}
?>
```

Works for me. Expand on that code and see when it breaks.

Answer (score -1):

Add a `die;` right after your `header:location`. This should do the trick.

Answer (score -3):

Chrome needs an http status first:

```
header("Status: 200");
header('Location:' . $url);
```

Comment: 200 with location? aren't PHP set status for you?

Comment: No, it does not help. And as far as I know the status code should be 30x (redirection).

Comment: Redirects are with 3xx status code, and you can put the status code as the second argument of header()